# Can I publish journal prompts if not a mental health professional?

Tags: self-publishing, self-preservation

I am designing a journal that includes prompts for "shadow work",  or rather, asks questions relating to one's dark side. The questions are intended to help the writer identify hidden aspects of him/herself and allow for greater self-awareness as well as acceptance. The prompts will ultimately lead  up to questions like, "how can I have greater compassion for myself when..." and are part of a larger framework to forge a healthy relationship with the shadow. However, some of the questions are difficult to answer, such as "what patterns of behavior do you not like about yourself?". My fear is that some of these questions may be triggering or lead to further mental health stress. Since I am not a mental health professional, I'm curious if I could ever get into legal trouble for publishing such prompts. Feedback greatly appreciated!

Comment: We can't give legal (or mental health) advice. As a frame challenge to the question: I'd assume your legal liability has more to do with any (implied) mental health benefits than a particular journaling prompt involved.... (My opinion is you don't actually need to prompt people to go INTO dark holes, the real trick would be to help guide them OUT of dark places – your technique seems to leave them on their own to work it out for themselves...? OK for stretching creative muscles but potentially hazardous for self-care.)

Comment: When you say "journal" do you mean something like a blank diary? So you are adding things like "column headings" or similar to a blank diary?